# Sumifs Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Iam using sumifs formula. My sumrange is dynamic and is based on the cell value. I have been able to get the column name by using the formula.

Now iam getting stuck when i try to reference the cell value(which has column name "g") to the range in sumifs, for example

=SUMIFS(LinkedIn!H:H,LinkedIn!A:A,Worksheet!B28). i want to change the range (H:H) with the column name which i have in the cell. i tried doing this "=SUMIFS(LinkedIn!D14:D14,LinkedIn!A:A,Worksheet!B28)" but its giving error.
please advise.

regards,
srijith

Comment: Can I assume "g" is in cell D14? and that if D14 is "g", you want your sumrange to be column G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:-
`=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("LinkedIn!" & D14),LinkedIn!A:A,Worksheet!B28)`

D14 should hold "H:H" or its equivalent.

Comment: You got me out of big trouble man!! It was like a dead end to me..exausted with searching google. You made my day Thank you!!! :)

Comment: It was a pleasure helping out.